# Would we like to have a linear circuit application to cause low distortion at the output port?

Tags: power, amplifier, power-amplifier, distortion, linearity

Would we like to have a linear circuit application to cause low distortion at the output port? What about a power amplifier? Is it necessary for a power amplifier to have only low distortion at the output port?

Comment: Yes, please. We would.

Comment: In addition we would like the device to use no power at all, be essentially free and come with a complimentary cake, be lightweight and small, work from 0 K to 950 K flawlessly and have adjustable bandwidth from 10⁻⁴ to 10¹⁸ Hz, please. Gain should be stable and far above 10⁶, while acceptable noise figure would be -0.2 dB. Export restrictions cause a lot of work, so please don't have these, either. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

> linear circuit application to cause low distortion

You self-answered that.

Distortion is anything that doesn't reflect the intended input/output behaviour. So, for a *linear* device, *distortion* is nonlinear behaviour. So yeah, if you call your device *linear*, it must have *low distortion*

> Is it necessary for a power amplifier to have only low distortion

Depends on what you're doing with that. Sometimes it does, other times you do things afterwards where linearity isn't as important.

Answer (score 0):

Often a simple resistor in the emitter of a bipolar transistor will produce adequately low distortion.

The IP2 and IP3 (not equal but close) for a simple bipolar is about -10 dBv.
(you need to derive that, and determine if dBv is Peak, PeakPeak or RMS.)

Inserting an emitter resistor, unbypassed, requires you re-derive the IP2 and IP3, which is a fine exercise.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on your application, for example, if you are making a hi-fi audio amplifier you don't want distortion, but if you are making a guitar amplifier, you may want distortion, in fact, musicians many times buy an amplifier based on how it distorts.

In other areas like communications, say power amplifiers, you may want distortion for the amplifier to work in its non-linear region and gain more efficiency (or better said, power added efficiency), if you care about the envelope of the signal you may want a clean no distortion power amplifier.

Check out the different classes of amplifiers, there are some meant to work in its linear region (like Class A), and others that are meant to distort (like Class F).